# How to align frame title of mdframed on custom place?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, mdframed

`mdframed` has an option of `frametitlealignment`, but the manual does not list possible values. I wonder if it accepts values other than `left`, `right` and `center` (apart from derivatives like `raggedleft`).

Is it possible to place the title in a custom place (e.g. 30% from left)?

If not, how to set padding (margin) for the title? I simply moved the title by

```
frametitle=\hspace{1em}Title
```

but the problem is that I use the title in the page header, and do not want this `hspace` there.

**EDIT:** MWE for clarification of the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\mdfdefinestyle{example}{settings={\@mkboth{\mdf@frametitle}{\mdf@frametitle}}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[style=example,frametitle=\hspace*{0.30\linewidth}Some Title 1]
\lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

As can be seen, by adding `\hspace` to the `frametitle`, not only the `frame title` shifts, but also the `page header` will do. I need to customize the position of frame title, but not the page header.

In fact, I cannot alter `frametitle`, as its value is exactly used in the page header. I need to align the frame title with `frametitlealignment`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `frametitlealignment={\hspace*{0.30\linewidth}}` to position the text to 30% the `\linewidth`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\mdfdefinestyle{example}{settings={\@mkboth{\mdf@frametitle}{\mdf@frametitle}}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[style=example,frametitle=Some Title 1,
frametitlealignment={\hspace*{0.30\linewidth}}]
\lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As I described, I use the frame title in the page header, I do not need this margin on my page header. If altering the content of `frametitle={}` it will be exactly displayed on the page header too.

Comment: Can you compose a MWE that shows the problem with this.

Comment: I added a MWE to clarify the problem.

Comment: @Ali: Ok, have updated to use `frametitlealignment`.

Comment: I had no idea that `frametitlealignment` can accept this kind of values :)

Comment: @Ali: Well, don't feel bad, neither did I. I just guessed correctly.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Should it be mention in the documentation?